# Scope confusion using delegate call

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

I am having trouble understanding the scope with delegatecall method. Here are my two contracts:

```
contract Caller {
     uint public testVar = 88;
     uint public myVariable = 6;

     function delegatecallExample(address _contract, uint newVar) public {
         _contract.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("updateMyVariable(uint256)")), newVar);
     }

}

contract CalledContract {
    uint public myVariable = 5;

    function updateMyVariable(uint newVar) public payable {
        myVariable = newVar;
    }

}
```

After deploying to a fresh remix instance, calling Caller.delegatecallExample with CalledContracts address and lets say 111, I observe that CalledContracts first declared variable (testVar in this case) is changed to 111 instead of myVariable. So what is the scope of delegatecall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Henk's answer, an important implementation detail is that the storage layout is also used from the calling contract.

Since you declare `testVar` first, as far as `CalledContract` is concerned, it is in the same storage location as the `CalledContract` `myVariable`. Thus, when delegate call sets `myVariable`, it is actually updating the storage of `testVar`.

If you switch the declaration order to:

```
contract Caller {
     uint public myVariable = 6;
     uint public testVar = 88;

     function delegatecallExample(address _contract, uint newVar) public {
         _contract.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("updateMyVariable(uint256)")), newVar);
     }

}
```

it will update `myVariable` instead of `testVar`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behaviour for `delegatecall`. `delegatecall` is like `call`, but the difference is the storage context functions run in. When `call`ing another contract, any functions that contract runs access their own storage. With `delegatecall`, however, the called contract accesses the storage of the caller.

In your example, `Caller` `delegatecall`s `CalledContract`. The function `updateMyVariable` accesses and updates the first element in storage of `Caller`, which is `testVar`, because `myVariable` points to the first storage element.

[Docs on `call` and `delegatecall`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#members-of-addresses)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your question was directly answered in the previous responses.

When any function is called - delegatecall or otherwise - the EVM loads the requisite pointers & values into that call frame's volatile stack/memory.

So unless you explicitly:

a) align caller+delegate contract storage

b) explicitly pass in the caller contract's storage reference addresses 
     as arguments to use in the function's call frame

your storage pointers are left up to the Delegate's standard function context.

Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm inducing.